# Vim Substitution Line by Line

Tags: vim, command, substitution, line-by-line

I would like to run a command such as `:s/write/run/` on a line by line basis.

We can specify a range of lines such as `:31,44s/write/run/`.

We can also search `:/write/` and press `n` to move to the next occurrence.

Is it possible to substitute in the same manner as search, by pressing a button and substituting the next occurrence?

Comment: Are you asking for a confirmation of a substitution? Just add the `c` flag. e.g. `%s/write/run/gc`

Comment: 'c' is for confirmation.  sweet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the book Practical Vim:

```
:%s/content/copy/gc
```

The c flag causes Vim to show us each match and ask “Replace with copy?” We can then say y to perform the change or n to skip it. Vim does what we ask and then moves to the next match and asks us again.

Comment: Or from `:help :substitute`.